# Microsoft Translator API Java, How to get client new ID with Azure

Tags: java, azure, clientid

Translate.setClientId("something");
Translate.setClientSecret("something1");

I had previously ran my code successfully using the following syntax, however, 50% of the time I will get an error saying: **TranslateApiException: Cannot find an active Azure Market Place Translator Subscription associated with the request credentials. :**

I had my app subscribed with the OLD website that Microsoft was using, but I think the problem is occurring because they are using Azure. Now, I have my app subscribed with Azure, I have a subscription for the Microsoft Translator API services. Was wondering how to set this to the NEW ClientID, ClientSecret that Azure provides.

This is the "old" site that I subscribed through first:
https://datamarket.azure.com/home/

Answer (score 7):

As the information from the old offical site(for translator [speech](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslatorspeech) & [text](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator) api) & [Announcements](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128340-announcements-action-required-before-april-30-20) said, "**THE MICROSOFT TRANSLATOR API IS NOW AVAILABLE ON THE AZURE PORTAL**" and "**Action Required before April 30, 2017 - Microsoft Translator Moves to Azure**". So if you want to use the Translator API now, you need to have an Azure subscription and create a Translator account of Azure Cognitive service like the offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account) said.

For example using Translator Text API, you can follow the new [tutorial](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html) to get an access token to build an `appid` for the API like my sample code in Java below.

```
// Get the access token
// The key got from Azure portal, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account
String key = "<your translator account key>";
String authenticationUrl = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";
HttpsURLConnection authConn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(authenticationUrl).openConnection();
authConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
authConn.setDoOutput(true);
authConn.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
IOUtils.write("", authConn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
String token = IOUtils.toString(authConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(token);

// Using the access token to build the appid for the request url
String appId = URLEncoder.encode("Bearer "+token, "UTF-8");
String text = URLEncoder.encode("happy birthday", "UTF-8");
String from = "en";
String to = "fr";
String translatorTextApiUrl = String.format("https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate?appid=%s&text=%s&from=%s&to=%s", appId, text, from, to);
HttpsURLConnection translateConn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(translatorTextApiUrl).openConnection();
translateConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
translateConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
String resp = IOUtils.toString(translateConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(resp);
```

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Man, you saved me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can to sign in through https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services

Then, you'll find a list of keys for all services under cognitive services:
[image]