# Microsoft Translator API error retrieving translation

Tags: java, azure, microsoft-translator

I'm simply trying to run this sample code below:

```
import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;
public class Translator {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Translate.setClientId("ID GOES HERE");

    Translate.setClientSecret("SECRET GOES HERE");

    String translatedText = Translate.execute("Bonjour le monde", 
    Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);

    System.out.println(translatedText);
  }
```

}

and I'm getting the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net
at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:202)
at com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:61)
at Translator.main(Translator.java:10)

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.getToken(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:133)
at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveResponse(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:160)
at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:199)
... 2 more
```

I know it seems like I'm not even trying to figure this out on my own but I'm a complete beginner and can't really understand the Exception trace at all by myself. I'm pretty sure I got the right client Secret. In my azure account I only see an application ID and an Object ID. I'm using the application ID as the client ID.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third party Java wrapper [`boatmeme/microsoft-translator-java-api`](https://github.com/boatmeme/microsoft-translator-java-api) for MS Azure Translator API is too old & unavailable, because it wrappered the old [Microsoft Translator - Text Translation](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator) which is old & unavailable now.
There is a notice at the page top of the site [`Azure datamarket`](https://datamarket.azure.com/home).

> DataMarket and Data Services are being retired and will stop accepting new orders after 12/31/2016. Existing subscriptions will be retired and cancelled starting 3/31/2017. Please reach out to your service provider for options if you want to continue service.

For using the new Azure Translator API on Azure portal, you need to refer to the document [Announcements: Microsoft Translator Moves to the Azure portal](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128340-announcements-action-required-before-april-30-20) to know how to create the new one on Azure portal and use it via the new REST APIs. Meanwhile, just as reference, you can see my answer in Java for the other SO thread [Microsoft Translator API Java, How to get client new ID with Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891510/microsoft-translator-api-java-how-to-get-client-new-id-with-azure/42898852#42898852).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to sort this out. And thanks for pointing out the duplicate post, I have deleted it.